# Uitableview cell changes value when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

The code below is creating a search for many strings. Initially there are 5 rows, when you reach row five, it adds another row. Instead of just directly editing the row, i load a filter controller (another view controller that as you type it completes words for you). When the user finishes finding a word he clicks it and comes back to this view controller. Now i want to fill the cell that was originally tapped with the text from the filter.

I tried asking earlier and didn't get any concrete answers.

I am running into a problem where when i scroll (after adding a new row), it starts filling in those rows with info already in the table, (as opposed to staying blank)

Please help me where i am going wrong

```
//global indexpath to remember which cell tapped
NSIndexPath *globalPath;
@interface SearchViewController ()

@end

@implementation SearchViewController

//Load implementation once per launch
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self linkInputTableToDelegate];
    _temporaryResultsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _flurryArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _numberOfSections=6;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
    [InputTable reloadData];

    textFromUserDefaults=[[[HelperMethods alloc]init]getObjectUserDefault:@"textFiltered"];
    [self addTextToFlurryArrayForFlurryAndSavedLists:_textFromUserDefaults];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

}

- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
     self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}

//Makes the input table respond to delegate table view methods
-(void)linkInputTableToDelegate{
    _inputTable.dataSource=self;
    _inputTable.delegate=self;
}

-(void)performSearch:(NSString*)text{
    //do search
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    int numberOfRows=_numberOfSections;

    //Rows for iPhone 4
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==480) {
        numberOfRows=numberOfRows;
        //Rows for iPhone 5
    }else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==568){
        numberOfRows=numberOfRows+1;
    }
    return numberOfRows;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //In reality groups are created with 1 row inside, this is to allow spacing between the rows
    return 1;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCellID = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID];
    }

    //Is the cell the same as the one clicked when going to ingredient filter
    BOOL cellIndexPathSameAsSelected=[self isCellIndexSameAsPreviousClicked:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    if (cellIndexPathSameAsSelected && _textFromUserDefaults!=nil) {

        if (![cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:_textFromUserDefaults]) {

            cell.textLabel.text=_textFromUserDefaults;
            [self performTextSearch:_textFromUserDefaults];
        }

    }
    return cell;
}

//Compares the previous clicked cell with the cell now selected
-(BOOL)isCellIndexSameAsPreviousClicked: (NSIndexPath*)cellPath{

    if (cellPath.row == globalPath.row && globalPath.section==cellPath.section) {
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)updateTableViewWithExtraRow :(NSIndexPath*)rowSelected{
    NSLog(@"number of sections =%i",_numberOfSections);
    if (rowSelected.section == _numberOfSections) {
        _numberOfSections ++;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    [[[HelperMethods alloc]init]saveObjectToUserDefaults:cellText :@"textFiltered"];
    globalPath = indexPath;
    [self updateTableViewWithExtraRow:indexPath];
}

-(void)addTextToFlurryArrayForFlurryAndSavedLists:(NSString*)text{
    if ([_flurryArray count]==0 &&[text length]>0) {
        [_flurryArray addObject:text];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<[_flurryArray count];i++) {
        NSString *textInArray=[_flurryArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if (![textInArray isEqualToString:text]) {
            [_flurryArray addObject:text];
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"Total number of saved items = %i",[_flurryArray count]);
}

// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Comment: The problem would appear to be `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You need to be looking at `indexPath` (generally `indexPath.row`) to figure out what you're going to put into the cell for that row of the table, but you're just grabbing `_textFromUserDefaults`.

Comment: I'm also surprised by `numberOfSectionsInTableView` where you're changing how many sections are in the table based upon the size of the screen. That's a little counter-intuitive, too. You should describe what you're trying to do here (not just `numberOfSectionsInTableView` but this whole view controller), because all of this is curious.

Comment: Finally, if you're trying to get blank entries, and you're seeing the contents of prior cells, that may well be because cells are dequeued and reused. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you're checking whether you should be setting the `textLabel`, but if the condition doesn't hold, you're not making sure to get rid of any `textLabel.text` that might already be there. Remember, cells are reused. Again, step back from the code, tell us what you're _trying_ to do, and then we can offer counsel.

Comment: Ok, this is creating a search for many strings. Initially there are 5 rows, when you reach row five, it adds another row (this goes on indefinetely) Instead of just directly editing the row, i load a filter controller (another view controller that as you type it completes words for you). When the user finishes finding a word he clicks it and comes back to this view controller. Now i want to fill the cell that was originally tapped with the text from the filter.

Comment: I've incorporated your comment into your question (whenever clarifying your question, it's best to edit the question directly, so users don't have to dig through comments to follow what's going on). Your updated comments clarify a bit, but I must confess it's still not entirely clear what you want to do, much less why you've tackled it the way you have. If you want to discuss, feel free to meet in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22276/uitableview-cell-changes-value-when-scrolling

Comment: Following on chat, thanks rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a couple of reactions looking at the code:

1. A couple of observations about the proper use of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods, specifically `numberOfRowsInSection`, `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

   - These really should be driven by some model data structure (e.g. a `NSMutableArray`) and nothing else;
   - These methods should be stateless. They should not relying on the value of some `NSString` instance variable, like `_textFromUserDefaults`) but rather always look up the value in the `NSMutableArray` model structure on the basis of the value of the `indexPath` parameter. You simply cannot make any assumptions about when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called. This may well account for your duplicate values.
   - None of these should be doing anything besides responding to the `UITableView` inquiry. For example, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is invoking `performTextSearch`. It really shouldn't do anything except return the cell.
   - Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` currently has conditional logic and only updates the cell if certain conditions holds. Because cells are reused, you really want to make sure that you initialize the cells regardless. You can't be assured that the cell is blank when you get it, nor that the previous contents are the previous values for that `indexPath`. Because cells are reused, it could be for an entirely different row. This could also account for your duplicative entries.
2. Regarding the interaction of the master view controller and the details view controller, there are more elegant ways than passing data back and forth via `NSUserDefaults`. For example when you initiate the details view controller, you could just pass it the information it needs. And when it's done, it should call a method in the master view controller to update the data in the master view. To do that, the master view controller should conform to some protocol of your own creation. If you see the example I shared via chat, you can see what that might look like. Anyway, by having some delegate method in the master view controller that the detail view controller calls when it's done, that eliminates the rather fragile technique of using `viewDidAppear` to control the updating of the master table view.
3. You might want to contemplate employing "edit" (which allows you to delete, possibly also edit a particular row) and "add" buttons like the standard "master-detail" template that Xcode provides. There are a number of standard conventions here that might be better than having an array of blank cells that you can then tap on. Clearly, your user experience is entirely up to you, but you can always contemplate whether there are existing, familiar conventions that you might employ.

Comment: Very interesting, 2 questions: What is the general pattern for doing something like this? (Than the blank array).  2. When you suggest a model do you suggest a dictionary to track indexpath and text? How would a mutable array keep it organized in the same order as the table would need it?

Answer (score 0):

Rob's feedback is good. In broader terms, you can't rely on the cells in a `UITableView` to hold onto their data. For efficiency, it will be creating, using, and destroying cells at will, and using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to figure out what they should look like. Instead of testing what's in a cell, you need to have your own set of data which describe the value of each cell, and just set the value based on the `indexPath`. I'd recommend storing all your cell information in an `NSMutableArray` which contains `NSString`s or something more complicated if necessary. It will be easy to set default values when you add cells to the array. Then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can just access the array rather than attempting its own logic based on current cells.